# Apps Script error: Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I see some people have had similar issues in the past, but they seems to be just different enough for the solution to be different. So here goes:

I'm trying to return a range of known size in Google Apps Scripts for sheets like so:

```
var myRange = ss.getRange(2,1,14,4);
```

However, I'm getting an error like this:

> Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number).

Note that using *a1notation*, as shown below, works just fine:

```
var myRange = ss.getRange("A2:D15");
```

The [`getRange` function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) has several permutations

- getRange(int, int)

  - returns a range from the coordinates of the ints
- getRange(int, int, int)

  - returns a range from the coordinates of the first 2 parameters of as many rows as the last parameter
- getRange(int, int, int, int)

  - returns a range from the coordinates of the first 2 parameters of as many rows as the 3rd parameter and as many columns as the last parameter
- getRange(string)

  - returns a range specified by the string in a1notation (i.e. "A2:D15", which is the same as saying everything from row 2 column 1 to row 15 column 4)

I've tried using all the different permutations (using hard-coded numbers), and only the *a1notation* one works. Any thoughts?

Comment: hum , I use  "getRange(int, int, int, int)" for my script and i don't have a prob...  Are you sure you take the good numbers ?

Comment: I can't see why that isn't working. Is there anyway you can post the full code?

Comment: is it possible that it might be because of your location settings? You might try a semi colons as separators instead of commas just for grins.

Comment: It would be useful to see how the var `ss` was defined.
Perhaps it's only looking at the active spreadsheet and not a sheet within it.

Comment: Even though using A1 notation doesn't cause an error, it still doesn't work.  Your code is not returning a range.  The spreadsheet can have multiple sheets in it.  The documentation is wrong.  It shouldn't be showing methods that get a range on the Spreadsheet class.  Getting a range will only work on the Sheet Class.

Comment: Thanks, all. Munkey and Sandy Good nailed it, as I wasn't defining which sheet to look in. Weird error, I'd say, but oh well.

Comment: @SandyGood  Agree with Sandy! The Apps script documentation is simply wrong. I faced the same problem today. You have to use getRange() on 'sheet' and not 'spreadsheet'. I don't know why the notation way works though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I'd be interested to see how you've built the `ss` var in your code.

It could be you're pointing to a spreadsheet, and not a sheet within that spreadsheet.

I've put together a simple example of the getRange. This works and it logs how many columns and rows in the range to the Logger.

As you can see, the `ss` var is used for the spreadsheet and the `sheet` var for the sheet within the spreadsheet itself.

```
function getSomeRange(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var myRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,14,4);

  Logger.log("Number of rows in range is "+myRange.getNumRows()+ " Number of columns in range is "+ myRange.getNumColumns());

}
```